# Plotting a flowchart-like figure in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if it would be possible to plot **the figure below** in **R** (colors don't matter)?:

[image]

Comment: Latex has a package called TikZ. I would reference you to the latex stack exchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this with base R plotting if you use some simple trigonometry to convert angles (`ang`) and distances from the origin (`r`)into cartesian coordinates

```
polar <- function(ang,r){
    return(cbind(
             cos(ang/180*pi)*r , 
             sin(ang/180*pi)*r
          ))
}
ang1 = seq(10,170,length.out=5)
ang2 = seq(10,170,length.out=20)
points1 = polar(ang=ang1,r=1)
points2 = polar(ang=ang2,r=2)
plot(points2, xlim=c(-2.5,2.5), ylim=c(-0.5,2.5))
points(points1)
for(i in 1:nrow(points1)){
    lines(rbind(c(0,0),points1[i,]))
}
for(i in 1:nrow(points1)){
    for(j in 1:4){
        lines(rbind(points1[i,],points2[(i-1)*4+j,]))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might have a look into the `igraph` package